# How can I determine if the MSR is finished reading the data from the Credit Card using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a specific textbox where when I swiped the credit card from MSR the value of the will be in there.

What I want exactly to happen is that I want to trigger a specific function after the card is swiped without using any buttons,etc I want to happen it automatically. And prompt the result of the function.

Is this possible?

Any advice or guide will be a big help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit card numbers are 12-19 characters in length.  The first six digits identify the issuer. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number for more details.

You could create a method that listens to `TextBox.TextChanged` and when the text length is at least 6 digits, get the issuer and then if the required length is reached then call your credit card processing number.

Also, some MSR can be programmed to send an end of text (ETX) character.

Hope it helps.